# creating generic method area()

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to add a static generic `Area()` method to calculate the sum of area of all shapes in my program. The method takes an ArrayList of shapes and returns the sum of area of all shapes. Declaring a bounded type parameter.

I have been reading about generic method, and started with something small but not sure how to progress, any help would be great still new to java.

```
public static <type> returnType methodName(){
```

Comment: I don't think you would need a generic method here. You are passing in an ArrayList of shapes right?

Comment: yep but I have two subclasses, a square class and a rectangle class in my program and a super class which is my shape class

Comment: so i need to implement the abstract area method in my subclasses

Comment: Is this homework?  Why do you think you need generics? What is your `Shape` class?

Comment: nah its a project im working on for my self

Comment: If the area can be derived from the abstract class, there's probably no need to restrict your method to a specific subtype.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use static method to calculate sum then you can write like:

```
public static double area(ArrayList<Shape> shapes){
     double sum=0;
     for(Shape shape: shapes){
          sum += shape.getArea();
     }
     return sum;
}
```

Comment: where did you get .getArea() from ?

Comment: getArea() method is to get the area of that shape, you could have any other name for it

Comment: so i have to create a getArea method in my other class ?

Comment: Yes, unless area parameter is declared public in your class.

Comment: would i declare it as a public or abstract ?

Comment: abstract class getArea { 
       return Math.PI * (width * height);
     }
like so ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't have the reputation to comment but to reply to your comment above, it would be a double/int getArea, not abstract class getArea. Abstract methods can't have implementation so declare the abstract method in your superclass then implement it in whichever subclasses need it.